# Emacs Not Properly installing on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, pi-b+

When I type:

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

It gives me multiple errors, such as:

`Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main imagemagick-common all 8:6.8.9.9-5+deb8u2 404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]`

and

`E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickwand-6.q16-2_6.8.9.9-5+deb8u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 5.153.225.207 80]`

Finally, at the bottom it tells me

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Even after I use the `sudo apt-get upgrade`command

I'm stuck... is there anything I can do?

Comment: If you have a gui running, check `http://5.153.225.207/` in a browser (if not, you could install `wget` and try that way); it seems to be running to me.  Also try `ping 5.153.225.207`.  That should also work.

Comment: Interesting. This doesn't seem to be your fault - the directory you've listed doesn't contain the file you're looking for (libmagickwand-6.q16-2_6.8.9.9-5+deb8u2_armhf.deb). It *does* contain libmagickwand-6.q16-2_6.8.9.9-5+deb8u3_armhf.deb (*note: deb8u2/deb8u3*). In addition to trying apt-get upgrade, have you also updated using sudo apt-get update?

Comment: That makes sense.  Imagemagick recently had a nasty security flaw found in it and so older versions were probably pulled from the repos; if you have not run `update` your local database will be unaware of those changes.